# How can Apache IoTDB query discontinuous data and to only keep one copy of duplicated data?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I wonder if Apache IoTDB can directly query discontinuous data within a certain period of time, that is, to keep only one copy if the data is duplicated? Now I need to query 30,000 time series at one time, and right know it is too slow to query them all and present them on one page. Our requirement is that if three fields of time series data are the same, it will be considered a duplicate record, and it can not be displayed when the page is rendered. I currently use Version 0.13 of IoTDB, are there any function that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jump function in Apache IoTDB. If you need to judge whether the three fields are the same, you can write the command like `select s1 from root.sg.d1 where diff(s1) != 0 or diff(s2) != 0 or diff(s3) != 0`.  However, this function can only be executed after Version 1.1.0, so you may need to upgrade IoTDB version.